# Animate images with a shorter blank interval between each frame?

Tags: ios, swift, ios-animations

I am able to create an animation out of an array of images I have using `.animationImages` and `.startAnimating()`, like so:

```
func animateSequence(images: [UIImage]) {

    let imagesOfDigits: [UIImage] = images

    canvasView.animationImages = imagesOfDigits
    canvasView.animationDuration = Double(imagesOfDigits.count) * 0.8
    canvasView.animationRepeatCount = 1
    canvasView.startAnimating()
}
```

However, I want a pause or perhaps a blank/`nil` frame shorter in duration (say, of 0.1) appearing in between each frame of my `imagesOfDigits` array that is being animated. That way, if there is an image in the array that looks exactly like the preceding one, it won't go unnoticed. Let's say if I have two consecutive images of the digit 8, the viewer will be able to tell easily that they were two 8s flashing one right after the other, as opposed to one image of an 8 that remained on screen for double the duration. I do want this pause in between frame to apply to all images, not just the ones that might look the same.

Comment: You can add a blank (plain gray color) image between each of your images in `imagesOfDigits`, but this will be an unnecessary overheadm and you cannot decrease the interval for only the blank images. 

If all you need is *some* visual indication that the image has changed, you can run another animation loop and change image view's border color (or background color if images are transparent / have insets so background color shows on the sides).